# Is it possible to disable uninstall option in app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, uninstallation

steps:

Settings -> Apps -> App info.

try to disable uninstall option.

Use case:

- If user try to uninstall the app, at that time try to call api.

I am using Device admin access.

Comment: You cant prevent any of the apps from uninstalling. Nor can you know when the app is uninstalled according to API 33

Comment: I wouldn't want any app to be able to entrench itself on my phone and refusing to uninstall. What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: If you are trying to lock down a device for some business reason, you should look up "kiosk mode".

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove the "Uninstall" option, but you can try setting some permissions to the user you want to

Comment: Is this possible to call api at that time of user uninstall?